# Why does grid-gap not work on mobile?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've been playing around with CSS Grid recently and have noticed something that I can't see to find the answer to. Let's say I split my page out to have 2 columns, and then a row below it, with another column (which spans both columns). On mobile, I'd like them to stack one on top of the other and then go back to layout described above after a certain breakpoint. Here is the markup:

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="upper">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lower">
    <div class="c">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.upper, .lower {
  display: grid;
}

.upper {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  background-color:grey;
  grid-gap:10px;

  @media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
  }
}

.lower {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows:auto;
  background-color: green;
  grid-gap:10px;
}
```

I've noticed that on mobile, even though I've defined `grid-gap` for both of my grid sections, on mobile when the columns stack, the `grid-gap` is not maintained. So in the fiddle below, when you make the window smaller, you can see that when the columns, stack one on top of the other, the gap between `B` and `C` is non existent. Here is the fiddle:

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9gwdr0ra/)**

Hope I'm making sense!

EDIT: Bear in mind I'm only testing this in Firefox and Chrome (which support grid).

Comment: Are you aware of that most browsers does not yet support CSS Grid? ... If it work on desktop but not mobile it is most likely no properly implemented yet  for mobile browsers

Comment: Yes I am, I'm testing in Chrome and Firefox, both of which have support for grid

Comment: I noticed that 'gap', an alias for 'grid-gap' is not supported by so much browser as grid-gap, so this could be a potential problem, if you just found this SO question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grid-gap` rule doesn't work between B and C because it doesn't apply.

This rule creates gutters between rows and columns *inside* a grid container.

But you are declaring `grid-gap` on `.upper` and `.lower`, two siblings in a *block container*. Their parent (`.grid`) is not a grid container because it doesn't have `display: grid` or `inline-grid`.

Therefore, `grid-gap: 10px` on `.upper` is creating a 10px gutter between A and B...

and `grid-gap: 10px` on `.lower` is creating a 10px gutter between.... *nothing* (`.lower` has only one grid item. `grid-gap` creates gutters between multiple grid items).

[fiddle demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/9gwdr0ra/3/)

For `grid-gap` to work among the `.upper` and `.lower` siblings you need to apply it to their parent, which must be a grid container.

[fiddle demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/9gwdr0ra/4/)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;    /* NEW */
  grid-gap: 25px;   /* NEW */
}

.upper, .lower {
  display: grid;
}

.upper {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 25px;
}

.lower {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px; /* does nothing unless there are multiple grid items */
}

@media ( max-width:800px ) {
  .upper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
  }
}

.upper > * { border: 1px dashed red;  }
.lower > * { border: 1px dashed blue; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <div class="upper">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
  </div>

  <div class="lower">
    <div class="c">C</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is a brilliant answer. Thank you so much!